# Filling nan of one column with the values of another Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataset that has been merged together to fill **missing values** from one another.

The problem is that I have some columns with missing data that I want to now fill with the values that aren't missing.

The merged data set looks like this for an **input**:

```
Name         State       ID       Number_x      Number_y       Op_x       Op_y
Johnson      AL          1        1             nan            1956       nan
Johnson      AL          1        nan           nan            1956       nan
Johnson      AL          2        1             nan            1999       nan
Johnson      AL          2        0             nan            1999       nan
Debra        AK          1A       0             nan            2000       nan
Debra        AK          1B       nan           20             nan        1997
Debra        AK          2        nan           10             nan        2009
Debra        AK          3        nan           1              nan        2008
.
.
```

What I'd want for an **output** is this:

```
Name         State       ID       Number_x      Number_y     Op_x       Op_y
Johnson      AL          1        1             1            1956       1956
Johnson      AL          2        1             1            1999       1999
Johnson      AL          2        0             0            1999       1999
Debra        AK          1A       0             0            2000       2000
Debra        AK          1B       20            20           1997       1997
Debra        AK          2        10            10           2009       2009
Debra        AK          3        1             1            2008       2008
.
.
```

So I want it so that all `nan` values are replaced by the associated  values in their columns - match `Number_x` to `Number_y` and `Op_x` to `Op_y`.

One thing to note is that when there are **two IDs that are the same** sometimes their values will be different; like `Johnson` with `ID = 2` which has different numbers but the same op values. I want to keep these because I need to investigate them more.

Also, if the row has two missing values for `Number_x` and `Number_y` I want to take that row out - like `Johnson` with `Number_x` and `Number_y` missing as a `nan` value.

Comment: why the 2nd last row one is 1 and the other is 10 ?

Comment: Sorry - correction made. Thank you.

Comment: also you have duplicated column in out put , _x and _y are the same ?

Comment: what about `df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1), :] = df.ffill()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let us do `groupby` with `axis =1`

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0],1).first().dropna(subset=['Number','Op'])
   ID     Name  Number      Op State
0   1  Johnson     1.0  1956.0    AL
2   2  Johnson     1.0  1999.0    AL
3   2  Johnson     0.0  1999.0    AL
4  1A    Debra     0.0  2000.0    AK
5  1B    Debra    20.0  1997.0    AK
6   2    Debra    10.0  2009.0    AK
7   3    Debra     1.0  2008.0    AK
```

Comment: astype(int) for `['Number','Op']`.

Comment: @pygo the original df should be float , that is why I keep it here. And that is just partial df.

Comment: @ W-B, ok nice solution, +1